# Makefile to link against Armadillo library using the PGI compiler

Tags: makefile, gpu, gnu, openacc

I am trying to use the -U__GNUG__  flag of the PGI compiler in a Makefile, attempting to compile all the .cpp files within a folder, linking against Armadillo(Using the g++ compiler, the code compiles and run.) The Makefile that I have is as follows:

```
CC=pgc++ 
CFLAGS= -U__GNUG__  -std=c++11 -fast -acc  -Minfo=accel -larmadillo -lgsl -w 

all: 
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} *.cpp -o cg 
clean: 
   rm -Rf cg pgprof* *.o core
```

It seems that the compilation of the objects file  is working, but fails compiling the final executable. What is  wrong with this Makefile?

Compiling the code using:

```
~$ make
```

I get the following errors:

```
cis.o: In function `arma::Col<double>::pod_type arma::op_norm::vec_norm_2<arma::Col<double> >(arma::Proxy<arma::Col<double> > const&, arma::arma_not_cx<arma::Col<double>::elem_type>::result const*)':
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/debug.hpp:173: undefined reference to `isfinite'
cis.o: In function `double arma::op_norm::vec_norm_2_direct_std<double>(arma::Mat<double> const&)':
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/debug.hpp:173: undefined reference to `isfinite'
cis.o: In function `void arma::arma_ostream::print_elem<double>(std::ostream&, double const&, bool)':
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/debug.hpp:173: undefined reference to `isfinite'
cis.o: In function `std::isfinite(double)':
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/debug.hpp:173: undefined reference to `isfinite'
cis.o: In function `bool arma::arma_isfinite<double>(double)':
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/debug.hpp:173: undefined reference to `isfinite'
davidson.o:davidson.cpp:(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN4arma7op_norm10vec_norm_2INS_11subview_colIdEEEENT_8pod_typeERKNS_5ProxyIS4_EEPKNS_11arma_not_cxINS4_9elem_typeEE6resultE+0x2bb): more undefined references to `isfinite' follow
pgacclnk: child process exit status 1: /usr/bin/ld
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

that is supposed to be fixed by including the flag -U__GNUG__.

Any  suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Is make using the command you expect it to be using to compile your binary? (You didn't include that in the pasted output.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the PGI pgc++ compiler where "std::isfinite" isn't being processed correctly in the presence of C++11.  Removing the "--c++11" flag will work around the problem.

I have added a problem report, PGI TPR#22065, and we hope to have the issue resolved in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer, but there are more problems because  the same code produces wrong results when it is executed after that it was compiled using pgc++. any idea?

Comment: Not off hand, though my guess is that the two issues are unrelated.  Can you post a small reproducing example for the wrong answer?